# Django: how to map model object to parameter and pass it to a method

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

here is my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    parentId = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    commitDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    countLike = models.IntegerField(default=0,editable = False)
    rootId = models.ForeignKey(Theme)
    userId = models.ForeignKey(User)

community_list(self,table,field):
    themeReply = len(table.objects.filter(field = themeId))
```

And I want to know how to pass the rootid, which is a library object to the `field`?

update my code and show how i make the call to `community_list` and how you assign the parameters:

```
def request_community_list(self,doObjects,table,field):
        returnTheme = {}
        if len(doObjects)!=0:
            if len(doObjects)<20:
                returnTheme['status'] = "lack"
            if len(doObjects)==20:
                returnTheme['status'] = "OK"
            returnThemeArray = []
            for i in range(len(doObjects)):
                backTheme = {}
                backTheme['themeId'] = doObjects[i].id
                backTheme['title'] = doObjects[i].title
                backTheme['schoolIdId'] = doObjects[i].schoolId_id
                themeCreateTime = str(doObjects[i].createTime)[:19]
                backTheme['createTime'] = themeCreateTime
                backTheme['tagSelf'] = doObjects[i].tagSelf
                backTheme['isImage'] = doObjects[i].isImage
                themeId = doObjects[i].id
                themeReply = len(table.objects.filter(field = themeId))
                backTheme['reply'] = themeReply
                returnThemeArray.append(backTheme)
            returnTheme["info"]  = returnThemeArray
            return json.dumps(returnTheme)
        else:
            returnTheme = {}
            returnTheme['status'] = 'nodata'
            return json.dumps(returnTheme)
```

Comment: Are you reading a `rootID` from the table or creating a new id? In any case create the class objects and then pass it to `community_list` which is straight forward as any other.

Comment: @nu11p01n73R just rootId parameter. I trying Article.objects.rootId_id... but it not work..and tell me it's a not a effective paramentor

Comment: show us how you make the call to `community_list` and how you assign the parameters

Answer (score 0):

```
community_list(self,table,field):
     articleInstance = Article()
     self.field = articleInstance.rootID
     themeReply = len(table.objects.filter(field = themeId))
```